# Openlayers 3 WKT writeFeatures rightHanded not working

Tags: gis, openlayers-3

After drawing a few polygons on a layer (named drawsource) I want to get the WKTs that make up the polygons to ingest into a SQL Server 2008R2 geography datatype. According to the documentation using `rightHanded:true` in the options of `writeFeature` should make the ring orientation counter clockwise (required for SQL Server). But the ring orientation always comes out clockwise unless I draw the features counter clockwise.

```
var WKT = new ol.format.WKT();
WKT.writeFeatures(drawsource.getFeatures(), { rightHanded: true, dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would answer it for anyone else encountering this problem.

It seems that this is only implemented for ol.format.GeoJSON.writeFeature.  A simple hack is:

```
var geoJsonFormatter = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var geoJson = geoJsonFormatter.writeFeature(feature, {rightHanded: true});
var rightHandCorrectedFeature = geoJsonFormatter.readFeature(geoJson);
var format = new ol.format.WKT();
var wkt = format.writeFeature(rightHandCorrectedFeature);
```